# How to properly insert/eject a drive from a hotswap bay?

Tags: windows-10, sata, power, hotswapping, drive-bay

I have a SATA disk I want to use into [an ICYDOCK bay](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B07B9GSK6M) (hotswap capable and hotswap enabled into the BIOS) that has a power button for the disk.

When I want to insert the disk on a running windows 10 :

- I ensure the bay if powered off
- I insert the disk into the bay
- Then I power it on with the power button on the bay

When I want to remove the disk on the running windows 10 :

- I "eject it safely" from Windows
- I power it off with the power button on the bay
- I remove it from the bay

Is this the correct way to do it ?
Or should I insert/remove it from the bay when it's already/still powered ?
The thing is that when I power off the bay before removing the disk, I hear a sound as if the heads of the disk were parking. That does not seems good to me.

Comment: Your process for the drive you have is correct as you laid it out.  Certainly "eject" in Windows first.

Comment: Read this review : https://www.forum-inside.de/topic.cgi?forum=14&topic=303

Comment: @harrymc:Read. But did I miss something ? What should I have noticed relating to my question ?

Comment: Nothing related to the question, just an article with some good advice and some warnings.